# Erlang / Misultin / erlsom error / process died

Tags: erlang, misultin

erlang code:

```
-module(index).
-compile(export_all).

-include_lib("erlsom/include/erlsom.hrl").

start(Port) ->
    misultin:start_link([{port, Port}, {loop, fun(Req) -> handle_http(Req) end}]).

stop() ->
    misultin:stop().

handle_http(Req) ->
    Var = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><request><code>1</code><var1>123456</var1><var2>qwerty</var2></request>",
    XmlErlsom = erlsom:simple_form(Var),
    Req:ok("~s", [Var]).
```

After I compiled the code and started the server, I opened localhost:8080/ and the shell gave me the following error:

```
http process <0.196.0> has died with reason: {badarg,
                                          [{erlang,list_to_binary,
                                            [[{ok,
                                               {"request",[],
                                                [{"code",[],["1"]},
                                                 {"var1",[],["123456"]},
                                                 {"var2",[],["qwerty"]}]},
                                               []}]]},
```

The same lib 'erlsom' for ChicagoBoss worked successfully...

After that i try with xmerl, but the result is similar.

Answer (score 1):

erlsom:simple_form returns tuple of the form {ok, ParsedData}:

```
A = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><request><code>1</code><var1>123456</var1>`<var2>qwerty</var2></request>".

> erlsom:simple_form(A).
{ok,{"request",[],
     [{"code",[],["1"]},
      {"var1",[],["123456"]},
      {"var2",[],["qwerty"]}]},
    []}
```

I believe you're trying to pass this returned tuple to Req:ok(), which expects list or binary or iodata or whatever else but tuple.

Comment: Thanks for reply! :) It's true, but when I get a third element of second element (I mean element(3, element(2, XmlErlsomResult)) ), the result in shell is: error in custom loop: {badarg,
                          [{io_lib,format,
                               ["~s",
                                [[{"code", ... etc }]

So the third element of second element is list or obviously I'm in wrong way. :(

Comment: First of all, what are you trying to accomplish? Why passing parsed struct to output when you have a raw string (Val in your example)?

Comment: My mistake, the last line is: Req:ok("~s", [XmlErlsom]). In the end, I just use Result = [tuple_to_list(X) || X <- Erlsom]. where Erlsom = element(3, element(2, XmlErlsom)) (from the example).